# Java program that returns a date when given a number and returns what day it will be in the future when given another number

Tags: java, case

Alright, so I'm trying to create a program that will return a day of the week when it is given a number from 0 to 6 (e.g. 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday....). Afterwards it will then ask the user for another number and it will calculate what day it will be in that many number of days. So it would look something like this:

Enter number: 0
Enter days that have passed: 4
It is Sunday and in the future it will be Thursday

I have tried a few different approaches and I cant seem to find one that works. Here is the latest thing I have come up with:

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
public class code
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter today's day:");
        int num = scanner.nextInt();
        
        if(num > 6 || num < 0) {
            System.out.println("This is an invalid number");
        }
        
        switch(num) {
            case 0:
                String day = "Sunday";
                break;
            case 1:
                String day = "Monday";
                break;
            case 2:
                String day = "Tuesday";
                break;
            case 3:
                String day = "Wednesday";
                break;
            case 4:
                String day = "Thursday";
                break;
            case 5:
                String day = "Friday";
                break;
            case 6:
                String day = "Saturday";
                break;
        }
        
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of days elapsed since today:");
        int num2 = scanner2.nextInt();
        
        
        
        int newday = num + num2;
        
        while(newday > 6) {
            newday = newday - 7;
        }
        
        switch(newday) {
            case 0:
                String day2 = "Sunday";
                break;
            case 1:
                String day2 = "Monday";
                break;
            case 2:
                String day2 = "Tuesday";
                break;
            case 3:
                String day2 = "Wednesday";
                break;
            case 4:
                String day2 = "Thursday";
                break;
            case 5:
                String day2 = "Friday";
                break;
            case 6:
                String day2 = "Saturday";
                break;
        }
            
        
        System.out.println("Today is " + day + " and the future day is " + day2);
    }
}
```

here are the errors that the compiler gave me:

```js
14 errors found:
File: C:\Users\exercise_4_5.java  [line: 19]
Error: variable day is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])
File: C:\Users\code.java  [line: 22]
Error: variable day is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])
File: C:\Users\code.java  [line: 25]
Error: variable day is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])
File: C:\Users\code.java  [line: 28]
Error: variable day is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])
File: C:\Users\cpde.java  [line: 31]
Error: variable day is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])
File: C:\Users\code.java  [line: 34]
Error: variable day is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])
File: C:\Users\code.java  [line: 55]
Error: variable day2 is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])
File: C:\Users\code.java  [line: 58]
Error: variable day2 is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])
File: C:\Users\code.java  [line: 61]
Error: variable day2 is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])
File: C:\Users\code.java  [line: 64]
Error: variable day2 is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])
File: C:\Users\code.java  [line: 67]
Error: variable day2 is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])
File: C:\Users\code.java  [line: 70]
Error: variable day2 is already defined in method main(java.lang.String[])
File: C:\Users\code.java  [line: 75]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable day
  location: class code
File: C:\Users\Desktop\code.java  [line: 75]
Error: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable day2
  location: class code
```

I am very new to programming and Java is my first language. Any help and fixes would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to elaborate on what didn't work.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

Comment: Where is it failing? Please edit the question to be precise

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;


/**
 *
 * @author wathsara
 */
public class Code {


    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String day="",day2="";
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter today's day:");
        int num = scanner.nextInt();

        if(num > 6 && num < 0) {
            System.out.println("This is an invalid number");
        }

        switch(num) {
            case 0:
                day = "Sunday";
                break;
            case 1:
                day = "Monday";
                break;
            case 2:
                day = "Tuesday";
                break;
            case 3:
                day = "Wednesday";
                break;
            case 4:
                day = "Thursday";
                break;
            case 5:
                day = "Friday";
                break;
            case 6:
                day = "Saturday";
                break;
        }

        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of days elapsed since today:");
        int num2 = scanner2.nextInt();



        int newday = num + num2;

        while(newday > 6) {
            newday = newday - 7;
        }

        switch(newday) {
            case 0:
                day2 = "Sunday";
                break;
            case 1:
                day2 = "Monday";
                break;
            case 2:
                day2 = "Tuesday";
                break;
            case 3:
                day2 = "Wednesday";
                break;
            case 4:
                day2 = "Thursday";
                break;
            case 5:
                day2 = "Friday";
                break;
            case 6:
                day2 = "Saturday";
                break;
        }


        System.out.println("Today is " + day + " and the future day is " + day2);
    }
}
```

Try the code above. the problem was you declared a string variable day 6 times and the string variable day2 6 times thats why the code didnt execute.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your solution is not very effective. It's about the algorithm, not the java language itself. Try this:

- Receive 2 inputs at once.
- Initialize an array or list from Sunday (index:0) to Saturday (index: 6)
- Sum those two inputs, and take the remainder when divide it to 7. I expect the result of the remainder is from 0 to 6
- Get the value of the array at index of the remainder

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, it was a simple fix. I declared the variables "day" and "day2" outside of the switch case statements instead of inside.

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
public class exercise_4_5
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter today's day:");
        int num = scanner.nextInt();
        
        if(num > 6 || num < 0) {
            System.out.println("This is an invalid number");
        }
        
        String day = "Invalid";
        
        switch(num) {
            case 0:
                day = "Sunday";
                break;
            case 1:
                day = "Monday";
                break;
            case 2:
                day = "Tuesday";
                break;
            case 3:
                day = "Wednesday";
                break;
            case 4:
                day = "Thursday";
                break;
            case 5:
                day = "Friday";
                break;
            case 6:
                day = "Saturday";
                break;
        }
        
        Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of days elapsed since today:");
        int num2 = scanner2.nextInt();
        
        
        
        int newday = num + num2;
        
        while(newday > 6) {
            newday = newday - 7;
        }
        
        String day2 = "Invalid";
        
        switch(newday) {
            case 0:
                day2 = "Sunday";
                break;
            case 1:
                day2 = "Monday";
                break;
            case 2:
                day2 = "Tuesday";
                break;
            case 3:
                day2 = "Wednesday";
                break;
            case 4:
                day2 = "Thursday";
                break;
            case 5:
                day2 = "Friday";
                break;
            case 6:
                day2 = "Saturday";
                break;
        }
            
        
        System.out.println("Today is " + day + " and the future day is " + day2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare those String variables in each switch case outside the switch and create onle day1 and day2, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things that make your code very inefficient. Here are some improvements

1. All repetitive code should be in a function. The code that takes a number and gets the day should be a different function (switch cases).
2. Use % (Mod) operator to get the day for the newDay rather than the while loop. `newDay = (num1 + num2)%7`
3. Instead of a switch case you could use a map.
4. The scope of `String day` and `String day2` are limited to inside the switch case, you cannot use them outside it. Declare the variable outside and just change the value inside the switch statement.

   ```
   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.Scanner;
   import java.util.Map;
   class Ideone {


       private static String getDay(int num){
           Map<Integer, String> days = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
           days.put(0, "Sunday");
           days.put(1, "Monday");
           days.put(2, "Tuesday");
           days.put(3, "Wednesday");
           days.put(4, "Thursday");
           days.put(5, "Friday");
           days.put(6, "Saturday");

           return days.get(num);
       }

       public static void main(String[] args){
           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Enter today's day: ");
           int num = scanner.nextInt();
           System.out.println("Enter the number of days elapsed since today: ");
           int num2 = scanner.nextInt();

           if (num < 0 || num > 6){
               System.out.println("Invalid Number");
               System.exit(0);
           }

           int newDay = (num + num2) % 7;

           System.out.println("Today is " + getDay(num) + " and the future day is " + getDay(newDay));

       }
   }
   ```